# c# Mutex Deadlocking

Tags: c#, mutex

We have the following code:

```
        public static Mutex AcquireMutex(string name)
        {
            bool ndgMutexAcquired;
            Mutex ndgMutex = new Mutex(true, name, out ndgMutexAcquired);

            if (!ndgMutexAcquired)
            {
                try
                {
                    ndgMutex.WaitOne();
                }
                catch (AbandonedMutexException)
                {
                }
            }

            return ndgMutex;
        }
```

I have a parent process where, inside a task, I call AcquireMutex, run some code, then release it.  In another task, I call a sub process, which also calls AcquireMutex with the same name, then immediately calls release.  It appears that this is deadlocking.  Only thing I think is that the "initially owned" parameter might need to be false like so:

```
        public static Mutex AcquireMutex(string name)
        {
            Mutex ndgMutex = new Mutex(false, name);
            try
            {
                ndgMutex.WaitOne();
            }
            catch (AbandonedMutexException)
            {
            }

            return ndgMutex;
        }
```

I don't really understand why that would help, but it seems to.  Can anyone help me understand why this might deadlock and what the proper fix is?

Here is the code that calls Acquire mutex in the child process

```
            using (var mutex = MutexExtensions.AcquireMutex(@"Global\auth_mutex"))
            {
                LogHelper.LogInfo("Releasing mutex since it was successfully acquired");
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
```

And in the parent process:

```
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Logger.LogInfo("Acquiring mutex ...");
                using (var mutex = MutexExtensions.AcquireMutex(@"Global\auth_mutex"))
                {
                    Logger.LogInfo("Auth mutex acquired");
                    // Stuff done here (external process call) ~~~~~~~~~~~~

                    // Mutex.Dispose doesn't implicitly release the mutex
                    Logger.LogInfo("Releasing mutex");
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();

                    return new TaskResult(true);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Where are you disposing of the Mutex? Additionally, you're not meant to create a new Mutex like that (you *can*, but only if you know what you're doing) - generally speaking `Mutex` objects should be `static readonly`. And most importantly: **never swallow a `AbandonedMutexException`!!!**. Microsoft makes this very clear in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Also is this for synchronization over separate processes, or just a single process? As my spidey senses are telling me you might not want a mutex at all...

Comment: What do you mean by "sub process"? (That's not a term used in Windows), do you mean a *real* child `Process` (a `Process` actually created by the parent process **without using `ShellExecute`**) or just some chunk of code? Also what do you mean by "In another task" exactly? (Don't forget that async `Task`s generally run on different threads, and `Mutex` has specific rules about using it from different threads) And please post the other code that tries to acquire the mutex - you've only posted half of it.

Comment: I am pinvoking CreateProcess to create a child process (I am doing this so the child process can write to the console correctly), and the child process is calling this method.  So completely different PID